# How to use the css of emotion with typescript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, emotion

I use [`emotion`](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) in a [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) with Typescript and I would like to use the [`css`](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) prop of emotion.

Following their [best practices](https://emotion.sh/docs/best-practices) I would like to define my styles in a `const` outside of my components, like so:

```js
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

const myStyle = css({
  backgroundColor: "red",
  display: "inline-block",
  height: 24,
  width: 24
});

export default function App() {
  return <div css={myStyle}></div>;
}
```

I followed their [instructions for setting up the `css` prop with Typescript](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript) and configured my Typescript compiler options like so:

```
"jsx": "react-jsx",
"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
```

however the style is not applied and instead a `div` containing the following message is rendered:

```
<div css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop)."></div>
```

Why are the styles not applied?

I also made a basic sample on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-glade-hgyk8x?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: This one works `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` inside App.tsx

Comment: I see. Apparently this is an issue with `create-react-app`: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9847. But the documentation of `emotion` is confusing, too: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2662

Comment: I had the same issue. Use the JSX Pragma in each file or set it global if possible.

https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma

FYI I switched to Vite where it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to import **@emotion/css** package, not **@emotion/react**, you can pass the className yourself.

like the code below:

```js
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

const myStyle = css({
  backgroundColor: "red",
  display: "inline-block",
  height: 24,
  width: 24
});

export default function App() {
  return <div className={myStyle}>Some text here</div>;
}
```

for more details you can read the documentation https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript

Comment: This does not allow me to use the `css` prop. Instead I'd have to use the `className` prop.

Comment: I'm so confused at this point... ripping emotion out of my app, doesn't seem to play since with typescript, react-bootstrap, other class names or anything really. All brand new react app modern updated everything... spent 3 hours trying to get a emotion class to combine with a bootstrap class, started in emotion css and moved to the react package, not going back, just giving up.